# When server comes up is there a way client application can know that server is up with unix domain sockets?

Tags: linux, unix-socket

Every time a server app  goes down and comes back up on the client application side I need to know so that I can connect to socket on client side. Iam using unix domain sockets. If the server goes down I get error on client side but if I want to know if there is a way to know if the server is up on client side without doing retries on connect

Comment: Can you `ping` that server?

Comment: When you lose a connection, about all you can do is retry to connect in a timer/loop until it is successful. Unless you make the client listen for a broadcast that the server can send when it comes back up.